# images change onHover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need many images to change when mouse hover on a image.Me try one but its change only one image how can i change many images on hover on image.My try [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="fimg"><a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="a.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div> <div class="simg"> 
<a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="A.jpg" alt="" /><p class="text_over_image" style="font-size:36px;">TEXT</p></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function(){
    $("#container").hover(function(){
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-130px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    }, function() {
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by many images? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/142/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy As you see in fiddle when when mouse hover it shows one image slide in,but i want more image to come

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i want more image to slide in the same container

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy any help?

Comment: That requires lot of html/css/js changes. So this is a broader question. You try to split your problems into smaller one and start to solve it one by one.

Comment: can you do some simple work images not slide but change on hover

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i tried alot from last 2 days but never got the result can you show me slide two image because in fiddle it shows only one image to slide

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, you want an image slider when you hover on the `container`.

The images are in inline-block are they are set to `white-space: nowrap`. So, that they don't wrap. `container` is set to `overflow: hidden`, it hides the extra images.

The images are shown by animating the `margin-left` of the inner div. So, it is like the inner container is moving but the container stays still.

You can modify it however you like, vertical animation, using css transitions and stuff.

I cannot post the code here because of the shortened url of the images.

You can test and modify it [here](http://codepen.io/Lavios/pen/vGdNGO), it's a pen.